# Is there any way to analyse the pattern passed to String.format(...)

Tags: java, string, format, formatter

I would like to analyse patterns that are ultimately passed to

```
String.format(String pattern, Object... args)
```

Let's consider the pattern

```
"Integer is %d, String is %s"
```

Is there a way that I can parse this pattern to determine that

1. arg0 will be formatted as a number
2. arg1 will be formatted as a String

Obviously I can do this with a regular expression but this gets much more difficult when indexes etc are specified in the pattern. For example let's consider another pattern

```
"String is %2$s, Integer is %1$d"
```

Here arg1 is specified before arg0 but the two patterns have the same formatters for the same arguments.

I'd really like to use core java classes to parse the pattern and analyse it but it seems like all of the methods are private. Under the hood, `String.format()` uses a [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Ultimately I'm trying to write a test case to validate my various language translation files and spot clashes (eg where one language specifies a date format and another specifies a number format for the same argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by borrowing the regular expression from the java source code.

```
public class MyTest {
    static class PlaceHolder {
        int index;
        String flags;
        Integer width;
        Integer precision;
        String type;
        String conversion;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("PlaceHolder[index=%s, conversion=%s, flags=%s, width=%s, precision=%s, type=%s]",
                    index, conversion, flags, width, precision, type);
        }
    }

    public List<PlaceHolder> getPlaceholders(String pattern) {
        // %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision][t]conversion
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("%((\\d+)\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.(\\d+))?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])");

        int nextImplicitIndex = 1;
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(pattern);

        List<PlaceHolder> placeholders = new ArrayList<PlaceHolder>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String sIndex = matcher.group(2);
            int index = sIndex == null ? nextImplicitIndex++ : Integer.parseInt(sIndex);
            String flags = matcher.group(3);
            String sWidth = matcher.group(4);
            String sPrecision = matcher.group(6);
            String type = matcher.group(7);
            String conversion = matcher.group(8);

            PlaceHolder placeholder = new PlaceHolder();
            placeholder.index = index;
            placeholder.flags = flags;
            placeholder.width = sWidth == null ? null : new Integer(sWidth);
            placeholder.precision = sPrecision == null ? null : new Integer(sPrecision);
            placeholder.type = type;
            placeholder.conversion = conversion;

            placeholders.add(placeholder);

        }
        return placeholders;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPlaceholders() {
        System.out.println(getPlaceholders("Integer is %d, String is %s"));
        System.out.println(getPlaceholders("String is %2$s, Integer is %1$d"));
        System.out.println(getPlaceholders("%,6.2f"));
        System.out.println(getPlaceholders("Today is %tB %te, %tY %n"));
    }
}
```

The test outputs the following:

```
[PlaceHolder[index=1, conversion=d, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=null], PlaceHolder[index=2, conversion=s, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=null]]
[PlaceHolder[index=2, conversion=s, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=null], PlaceHolder[index=1, conversion=d, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=null]]
[PlaceHolder[index=1, conversion=f, flags=,, width=6, precision=2, type=null]]
[PlaceHolder[index=1, conversion=B, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=t], PlaceHolder[index=2, conversion=e, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=t], PlaceHolder[index=3, conversion=Y, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=t], PlaceHolder[index=4, conversion=n, flags=, width=null, precision=null, type=null]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For an open source project, you can base your own TestFormatter on the source of [Formatter (source)](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Formatter-source.html). Then, in the switch case of the `format`() method, remember the argument types as follows:

Code:

```
argument = args[argumentIndex];

switch (conversion) {
    case 'b':
        argumentHashMap.put(new Integer(argumentIndex), Boolean.class);
        booleanFormat(argument, flags, width, precision, origConversion);
        break;
    case 's':
        argumentHashMap.put(new Integer(argumentIndex), String.class);              
        stringFormat(argument, flags, width, precision, origConversion);
        break;
    case 'd':
        argumentHashMap.put(new Integer(argumentIndex), Double.class);              
        decimalConversion(argument, flags, width, precision, origConversion);
        break;
    ...
```

I have added the lines with `argumentHashMap`.